# cleaning up unmanaged c++ thread on c# application exit

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading

Here's my setup:
1) c# application starts up and calls an exported unmanaged c++ dll function 
2) the dll function spawns a thread via win32 CreateThread
3) this new thread does it's "work" in a while loop, checking for an exit flag

When I exit the c# application, the thread exits immediately.

Questions:
1) What can I do to allow my thread to cleanup before exiting?

Much thanks - I am new to the c# world, but experienced with c++

Comment: Why not have the C# app set the exit flag and wait on the thread handle upon app exit?

Comment: maybe this is all that I am missing, how do I capture the "exit" event in the c# app?

Comment: @user371602 : Every C# app has a `Main` entry-point, just as C++ apps have `main`. As a **naive** first step, try wrapping its contents in a `try..finally` and wait on the thread in the `finally`. There are almost definitely better ways, but it depends on the type of app. Console? WinForms? WPF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your C# app exits:

1. Set a flag visible to the thread.
2. Call `WaitForSingleObject` on the `HANDLE` returned by `CreateThread`.  This will make it wait for the thread to exit.
3. Optionally be a good citizen and call `CloseHandle` on the thread's `HANDLE` to free its resources, though this doesn't really matter if the app is about to exit.
4. Periodically check this flag inside your thread to see if it should exit the loop.